# How to refactor a function that throws exceptions?

Tags: scala, exception, refactoring

Suppose I am refactoring a function like this:

```
def check(ox: Option[Int]): Unit = ox match {
  case None => throw new Exception("X is missing")
  case Some(x) if x < 0 => throw new Exception("X is negative")
  case _ => ()
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the exceptions but I need to keep the `check` signature and behavior as is, so I'm factoring out a pure implementation -- `doCheck`:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def doCheck(ox: Option[Int]): Try[Unit] = ???

def check(ox: Option[Int]): Unit = doCheck(ox).get
```

Now I am implementing `doCheck` as follows:

```
def doCheck(ox: Option[Int]): Try[Unit] = for {
  x <- ox toTry MissingX()
  _ <- (x > 0) toTry NegativeX(x)
} yield ()
```

Using the following `implicits`:

```
implicit class OptionTry[T](o: Option[T]) { 
  def toTry(e: Exception): Try[T] = o match {
    case Some(t) => Success(t)
    case None    => Failure(e)
  }
}

implicit class BoolTry(bool: Boolean) { 
  def toTry(e: Exception): Try[Unit] = if (bool) Success(Unit) else Failure(e) 
}
```

The `implicits` certainly add more code. I hope to replace `OptionTry` with an `implicit` from `scalaz/cats` someday and maybe find an analog for `BoolTry`.

Comment: I think you made things more complicated.If check does not throw Exceptions anymore, what is the purpose of calling it?

Comment: `Success(Unit)` should be `Success(())`

Comment: @mavarazy `check` does throw exceptions. The refactoring doesn't change  the original `check` behavior. (Updated the question to make it clear).

Comment: @Łukasz Could you explain why `Success(())` is better than `Success(Unit)` ?

Comment: Because `Unit` is companion object and has type `Unit.type`, while `()` is  the only value of type `Unit`. Your code only works because `()` is added implicitly after the `Unit` expression. Similarly given `def a = 5` and saying `val t: Try[Unit]  = Success(a)` gives a `Success(())`.

Comment: @Łukasz Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could refactor with a loan pattern and `Try`.

```
def withChecked[T](i: Option[Int])(f: Int => T): Try[T] = i match {
  case None => Failure(new java.util.NoSuchElementException())
  case Some(p) if p >= 0 => Success(p).map(f)
  case _ => Failure(
    new IllegalArgumentException(s"negative integer: $i"))
}
```

Then it can be used as following.

```
val res1: Try[String] = withChecked(None)(_.toString)
// res1 == Failure(NoSuchElement)

val res2: Try[Int] = withChecked(Some(-1))(identity)
// res2 == Failure(IllegalArgumentException)

def foo(id: Int): MyType = ???
val res3: Try[MyType] = withChecked(Some(2)) { id => foo(id) }
// res3 == Success(MyType)
```