# How to refactor a function that throws exceptions with Scalaz or Cats

Tags: scala, refactoring, scalaz, scala-cats

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906243/how-to-refactor-a-function-that-throws-exceptions):

Suppose I am refactoring a function like this:

```
def check(ox: Option[Int]): Unit = ox match {
  case None => throw new Exception("X is missing")
  case Some(x) if x < 0 => throw new Exception("X is negative")
  case _ => ()
}
```

I am writing a new pure function `doCheck` to return either `Unit` or an exception.

```
case class MissingX() extends Exception("X is missing")
case class NegativeX(x: Int) extends Exception(s"$x is negative")

import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Result[A] = Excepiton \/ A

def doCheck(ox:Option[Int]): Result[Unit] = for {
  x <- ox toRightDisjunction MissingX()
  _ <- (x >= 0) either(()) or NegativeX(x)
} yield ()
```

and then invoke it from `check`

```
def check(ox:Option[Int]): Unit = doCheck(ox) match {
  case -\/(e) => throw e
  case _ => ()
}
```

Does it make sense ? Would it be better to implement `doCheck` like that ?

```
def doCheck(ox:Option[Int]): Result[Int] = for {
  x1 <- ox toRightDisjunction MissingX()
  x2 <- (x1 >= 0) either(x1) or NegativeX(x1)
} yield x2
```

How to implement it with `cats` ?

Comment: Why do you still throw the exception in `check` ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens I don't want to change all the code outside `check`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do pretty much the same in cats, only cats itself has no `Boolean => Xor[A, B]` syntax like the `either () or ()` from scalaz.

```
import cats.data.Xor
import cats.implicits._

def doCheck(ox: Option[Int]): Xor[Exception, Unit] =
  ox.toRightXor(MissingX()).flatMap(x => if(x > 0) ().right else NegativeX(x).left)
```

You could use [mouse](https://github.com/benhutchison/mouse), which provides similar syntax helpers for cats :

```
import com.github.benhutchison.mouse.boolean._

ox.toRightXor(MissingX()).flatMap(x => (x > 0).toXor(NegativeX(x), ()))
```

`Xor` also has the method `ensure` to do something like this, but it doesn't give you access to the element if the predicate doesn't hold. If you didn't need the `x` for `NegativeX`, you could have written :

```
ox.toRightXOr(MissingX()).ensure(Negative())(_ > 0).void
```